# How to put data in Highchart from session storage?

Tags: javascript, html, session, highcharts, session-variables

I'm trying to load data in a pie highchart from session storage variable, but I'm not getting any result.

I want this:

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Delivered amount',
        data: [
            ['Bananas', 8],
            ['Kiwi', 3],
            ['Mixed nuts', 1],
            ['Oranges', 6],
            ['Apples', 8],
            ['Pears', 4],
            ['Clementines', 4],
            ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
            ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
        ]
    }]
});
```

});

and I'm storing information in a session variable like this:

```
sessionStorage.data = "['Bananas', 9], ['Kiwi', 9]";
```

Then, I put this variable in data field:

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Delivered amount',
        data: sessionStorage.data
    }]
});
```

});

what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the session data as string and then you try to set Highcharts data to that string - you should unserialize it to javascript array.

If you change the format of the `sessionStorage.data` like this:

```
'[["Bananas", 9], ["Kiwi", 9]]'
```

you can use `JSON.parse` to unserialize it:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.data)
}]
```

Comment: It works! Now I understand how to use session data in highcharts with JSON parsing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
series : [[{name: 'Delivered amount',data: sessionStorage.data}]
```

to

```
series = [[{name: 'Delivered amount',data: sessionStorage.data}]
```

Comment: I can't do this because highcharts syntax must be with ":"